# Does $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} \, dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function, then if $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges, does $\int_0^1\frac 1 {f(x)} \, dx$ converge? I answer is yes, because $\frac{1}{x^2}$ converges, but $1\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ also converges. in the range $[0,1].$ And in general its true.

Comment: You found one example where the claim is true. That doesn't necessarily mean it's true in general.

Comment: If you're struggling with the language, try translate.google.com/

Comment: Your example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is wrong because $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ doesn't converge.

Comment: @jjagmath yes that's typo. I change it to 1

Comment: Also I can speak English, maybe not well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x)\equiv 0$ is continuous, $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges, but $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is not even defined.

Edit:

After the edits done to the question:

$\displaystyle \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(x)}\,dx$ evaluates $f$ at different points with the only exception of $x=1$. The values of $f$ at $(1,\infty)$ in no way can influence the behavior of $f$ in the interval $[0,1)$, the only condition is that the function must glue well at $1$. The function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x\in [0,1]\\
1/x^2 & x \in [1,\infty)
\end{cases}$$

is continuous, $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges but $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(x)}\,dx$ diverges.

This function is not strictly greater than $0$ because $f(0) = 0$.

Another edit:

If you want the additional requirement that $f(x)> 0$ for all $x$ then $\frac{1}{f(x)} > 0$ and is continuous in $[0,1]$. Then $\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(x)}\,dx$ converges just because $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is a continuous function in $[0,1]$, it has nothing to do with the convergence of $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Sorry another condition is $f(x)>0$, so what happens then?

Comment: And sorry it's $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ there. It's typo.

Comment: @Crue I updated my function. Now it's $>0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, consider the functon $f(x)$ that's $x$ in $[0,1]$, $e^{1-x}$ everywhere else.

Another simple one: $f(x) = \exp(-x - 1/x)$.

Comment: I suspect OP meant $2-x$ on the interval [1, 2] (for continuity). The behavior outside of the (0,1) interval is essentially irrelevant, though — we can staple $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ to any function $g$ with $g(1)=1$ and $\int_1^\infty g(x)dx$ convergent.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks, I fixed it. Also made sure it's always $>0$.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Those functions are $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @jjagmath If you want to also include $x=0$, that means $f(x)\ge \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Then $1/f(x) \le 1/\epsilon$ and so $\int_0^1 1/f(x) \le \int_0^1 1/\epsilon = 1/\epsilon$. So yes, in that case it always converges.